# python 3.6 failing to convert string to json

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to convert the following string to json with json.loads():

```
targetingConditions = "[{\"filters\":[{\"key\":\"domain\",\"rel\":\"neq\",\"values\":['science.howstuffworks.com', 'conduit.com', 'usatoday.com']}]}]"
```

I know that the backslashes may cause the problem as I've seen in similar questions and answers. I have tried to replace the backslashes with double backslashes like this:

```
targetingConditions.replace('\\', '\\\\')
```

and any other thinkable option or example that I found in similar problems' answers.

the code is:

```
json.loads(targetingConditions)
```

the output I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/uesr/Google Drive/SHARED/Automation project/Automations/streamrail/tests.py", line 36, in <module>
tag_filters = json.loads(tag_filters)
  File "C:\Users\uesr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\uesr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\uesr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 52 (char 51)
```

Comment: The string *is*  (almost) JSON; you want to *decode* it to a Python data structure. The problem is the single quotes, which aren't valid JSON.

Comment: The string is not valid JSON. JSON strings cannot be single-quoted. How was the string generated? If it’s hardcoded like in the example, why not just hardcode the list itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string isn't valid JSON.  JSON only accepts double quotes, so you'll need to replace the single quotes in `targetingConditions`

```
targetingConditions = '[{"filters":[{"key":"domain","rel":"neq","values":["science.howstuffworks.com", "conduit.com", "usatoday.com"]}]}]'
```

This allows you to wrap everything in single quotes, which means you don't have to escape anything.  You can then make this a python object with `json.loads` or just write it directly to a file.  You may find the [JSON specification](https://json.org/) useful in the future, or use a pre-built [JSON validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I believe your json string is bad, as I tried to parse it in JavaScript and gave me this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 51
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at <anonymous>:1:6
```

But if you change the the string to

```
"[{\"filters\":[{\"key\":\"domain\",\"rel\":\"neq\",\"values\":[\"science.howstuffworks.com\", \"conduit.com\", \"usatoday.com\"]}]}]"
```

It will work now since JSON's string are enclosed as with double quotes instead of single quotes. Single quotes are possible way to denote a string in python but for JSON the only method in double quotes.

Also you don't need to replace the \ with \\ as the \" is denoting the double quote.

Comment: Thank you very much